# How can i read and store mouse coordinates while the rest of the function does not do much, pretty much stall?

Tags: matlab, time, while-loop, coordinates, mouse

so i have a matlab function below that returns a matrix of [x y time_elapsed] coordinates from 'start' to 'target', and 'target' is reached when it is at distance of acc_length to it. the time_elapsed is to help me get the speed profile.

Currently, this works fine with sampling roughly every 0.01s and there is a 2-second pause when starting the motion from 'start'.

My question is how can i do the same thing - having the user to wait 2s once 'start' position is reached, but instead of pausing the program, **how can I still read the mouse coordinates(within the 2s period) while nothing useful happens for 2s?**

P.S. i want to get these coordinate to calculate the precision of user to the start.

```
function arr = pmove(start, target, acc_length)
uimenufcn(gcf,'WindowCommandWindow');

arr = [];
checkStart = 1;
checkEnd = 0;

while checkStart
    pt = get(0,'PointerLocation');
    pt = [pt(1) - 1920/2, pt(2) - 1080/2];
    d = pdist( [start; pt] );

    if ~checkEnd & d <= acc_length;
        disp('Start moving to target after 2 seconds.')
        pause(2);
        pt = get(0, 'PointerLocation');
        pt = [pt(1) - 1920/2, pt(2)-1080/2, 0];
        arr = cat(1, arr, pt);
        checkEnd = 1;

        tic;
        continue;
    end

    if checkEnd
        d = pdist( [target; pt] );
        t_elapsed = toc;
        pt = [pt , t_elapsed];
        arr = cat(1, arr, pt);

        if d <= acc_length
            checkStart = 0;
        end
    end

    if ~isempty(arr)
        figure(gcf)
        hold on;
        plot(arr(:,1), arr(:,2) );
        %drawnow;
        axis equal;
    end
    pause(0.01);

end
```

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using another while-true loop and checking the time_elapsed, if it is longer than 2.1s (tolerance of 0.1s for the user) i break out of the loop. During which, i get the pointer cordinates about every 0.01s and run my calculations.

```
tic;
while 1
    pt2 = get(0,'PointerLocation');

    % calculation

    time_elaps = toc;
    if time_elaps > 2.1       % tolerance of 0.1s
        break;
    end
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Comment: please add some description of your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `pause(2)` line with:

```
for i=1:200
    pt2 = get(0, 'PointerLocation');
    % do your calculation
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Comment: ideally this for-loop would run for 2s, however the reality is that this loop would take longer than that, and i think there has to be another cleaner way to do so?

Comment: if not, i can get the time elapsed value using 'toc' and break out of loop if it exceeds 2s...but there has to be a better way in my opinion..

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad You can run main while-loop and `pause(2)` in separated threads if calculation takes much time. BTW, there is no solution that you can guarantee that will take exactly 2 seconds, it's all about how much tolerance you can bear.

Comment: yes i understand that 2 seconds is not guaranteed. but i tried running the loop you suggested with my calculations included and the time taken was in fact larger than 3s, and the tolerance i want is in milliseconds. 

in the end, i've decided to break out of loop once it's longer than 2s.

Comment: @SuhaibAhmad What you suggested as an edit is actually another answer! Post it as a new answer.